# How to wrote programs to implement shared memory page in C

Tags: c, linux, gcc, shared-memory

I have a C program which perform encryption/decryption operation using OpenSSL. I want to implement the concept of Shared memory pages using the
above program. For that purpose I wish to perform same encryption/decryption operation using OpenSSL in two separate C program.

How can I write to implement shared memory page concept
so that ONLY One copy of OpenSSL library is loaded ? Is it if I use OpenSSL , automatically shared memory page concept will be implemented Or I need to write program with any special manner ?

I am using GCC under Linux.

Any pointer / help will be great help.

Comment: If you're linking with the shared OpenSSL library, there already is only one copy of the library in memory, that's why it's called *shared* library.

Comment: Thanks @ Joachim. I just want to know if my program2 use OpenSSL to perform encryption/decryption then the code will be loaded into main memory/cache , so later if I run program1 which also use OpenSSL for similar encryption/decryption on different data, will it take use shared memory of OpenSSL library automatically Or I need to do programatically.